# Updating InnerHTML of a DIV on Keypress event of a textbox

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

I am want to have a input box, where a user can add or change text, and at the same time (or after they have finished), I want to update the text inside a div, with the text they just typed.

this is the code I used

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
function change(boxid,divtoaffect) { 
content = document.getElementById("" + boxid + "").value; 
document.getElementById(divtoaffect).innerHTML = content; 
} 
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" style="border-bottom:1px solid black; border-right:1px solid black; border-left:1px solid black; border-top:1px solid black" width="50%">
<tr>
    <td >Name:<br/><input type="text" id="text1" onKeyPress="change('text1','output1')"  /></td>
    <td valign="bottom"><div id="output1" style="font-weight:bold;height:20px;"></div></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Designation:<br/><textarea id="text2" rows="1" onKeyPress="change('text2','output2')"></textarea></td>
    <td valign="bottom"><div  id="output2" style="height:40px;"></div> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Address:<br/><textarea id="text3" rows="2" onKeyPress="change('text3','output3')"></textarea></td>
    <td valign="bottom"><div id="output3" style="height:50px;"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

The problem here is that it updates the DIV when I type the second word in the textbox,i.e when I type a single word it doesn't show up in the DIV and when I type the second one it shows the first word in the DIV.

[image]

[image]

And also when I Press Enter in the Textarea field , in the DIV it continues on the same line. Here's the Image
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `onKeyPress`, use the `onKeyUp` event

EDIT: Extended question.

You need to convert a carriage return (+ linefeed) into a `<br />` tag. Something like below (replace at end of the line)

```
function change(boxid,divtoaffect) { 
  content = document.getElementById("" + boxid + "").value.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
  document.getElementById(divtoaffect).innerHTML = content; 
}
```

Note that you may need to replace `\r\n` (carriagereturn + linefeed) instead of `\n` (linefeed). Example below

```
content.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br>'); 
content.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Comment: I can type on the next line when I press ENTER. But when I press ENTER to go to the third line, it doesn't type in the DIV corresponding to it....what am I missing here...???

Comment: I think you mean that it looks like the text is outside the `div`. It is because you set height to 50px. If you make it `min-height` instead of `height`, or add style `overflow-y:auto;` it will look better

Comment: Thanks I figured that out. I had kept `overfow:hidden`. i changed it to `overfow:visible`